# defining a private member function outside class definition and use of static data

Tags: c++, class, oop, static

I have two questions for given class Rectangle.

```
class Rectangle{
private:
int l;
int w;
static int count;
};
```

1) how do I define different private, public and protected functions outside the class definition? also how can i make them static function?

2) A private variable cannot be accessed outside the class definition, but a static data can be called directly using class name without creating any object. Can i access private static data count directly in main() function, like `Rectangle.count=1` ? If no, should i always declare static data as public?

I know that we define member function using scope operator. but i don't know how to make them private or public.

```
int Rectangle::area()
{
return l*w;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "define different private, public and protected functions outside the class definition"? Can you please try to elaborate? And the answer to both your questions should be in any [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558).

Comment: @Ayush Gupta It is a too broad question. Read a book on C++.

Comment: i tried looking up for answer but i couldn't find it. I was asking, if this area() function will public or private? if it is public function, how can i make it private or protected?

Comment: That is really basic C++, and even pretty bad books should have taught you how to *declare* a member function inside the class, and them *define* (implement) it outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Definition of class member functions outside the class definition:

   ```
   class Rectangle {
   public:
       int area() const;         // member function declaration
   private:
       int l;
       int w;
       static int count;
   };

   int Rectangle::count = 0;     // initialization of the static variable 

   int Rectangle::area() const { // member function definition
       return l * w;
   }
   ```
2. > Can i access private static data count directly in `main()` function, like `Rectangle.count=1` ? If no, should i always declare static data as public?

   No and no. Making it accessible from outside the class would be no different from making it a global variable, and if that's what you want, make it a global variable. Otherwise, only let `Rectangle` objects, static member functions or `friend`s access the static data. You *could* for example make `main()` a friend of the class to let it get raw access to the data (both in `Rectangle` objects and the `static` data):

   ```
   class Rectangle {
   private:
       friend int main();
   };
   ```

   but this should be avoided if you can. It's most often better to create member functions for accessing the raw data - or else you'd suddenly have `main()` changing the `count` value which I guess would be a terrible idea in this case.

> I know that we define member function using scope operator. but i don't know how to make them private or public.

They are what you declared them to be in your class definition. If they are declared `public`, they will be public etc.

---

Example of an instance counter:

```
class Rectangle {
public:
    Rectangle(int L, int W);
    Rectangle();
    ~Rectangle();

    int area() const;

    static unsigned get_count();

private:
    int l;
    int w;
    static unsigned count;
};
```

```
unsigned Rectangle::count = 0;

unsigned Rectangle::get_count() {
    return count;
}

Rectangle::Rectangle(int L, int W) : l(L), w(W) {
    ++count;
}

Rectangle::Rectangle() :
    Rectangle(0, 0) // delegate
{}

Rectangle::~Rectangle() {
    --count;
}

int Rectangle::area() const {
    return l * w;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    {
        Rectangle r;
        std::cout << Rectangle::get_count() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << Rectangle::get_count() << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

Comment: A `friend` can also access `private` data of a class, whether `static` or not.

Comment: @Peter True.  I'm not sure how to fit that into the question without complicating it though.

Comment: maybe change the last sentence responding to point 2 to read "Otherwise, only let Rectangle objects, static member functions access, or friends access the static data."

Comment: @Peter Ok, I gave it a try. Thanks!